# Is there a 3-approximation algorithm for the TSP problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation

I know the double tree algorithm and Christofides algorithm with 1.5 approximation ratio. We got this question from the teacher.

Comment: Just to clarify, your teacher asked if there is a 3-approximation algorithm for TSP? What definition of an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm are you using? By the standard definition, if $\beta \leq \alpha$ then any $\beta$-approximation algorithm is also an $\beta$-approximation algorithm.

Comment: Do you know more about the class of instances, e.g. is it metric?